# Running Class fixtures in a Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, fixtures, visual-studio-test-runner

I've been doing some build validation testing for a project. I'm running two tests. The class running those tests has a class fixture that is configuring and running the set up and tear down before and after the tests are ran.

I'm using Visual studio to implement the BVTs and the test are running fine here locally. However, I deployed the repository with the BVTs to Azure Dev Ops release pipeline using the Visual Studio Test stage and its failing.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops), you need to build the related projects within the solution at first. Then use the output DLL files to do the tests.

If you want to directly run the test project without an addition previous build step, you can check out the source code into the pipeline working directory, then use the [.NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to execute the '**`dotnet test`**' command with the test project.

The '**`dotnet test`**' will automatically build all the related projects before starting the tests.

For example, there are two projects within the same solution:

- The class library project: **`MathCalc/MathCalc.csproj`**
- The test project to test the class library: **`TestMathCalc/TestMathCalc.csproj`**

Using below task can directly execute the test project without adding a previous build step.

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: TestMathCalc/TestMathCalc.csproj
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration)'
    testRunTitle: 'TestMathCalc.TestOperators_$(Release.ReleaseId)'
```

Comment: Hi Bright, thanks for answering my question. I have set that up in a yaml pipeline already. My issue starts at the release pipeline though. Both test are failing with exceptions. However, I do not face these issues when running locally.

Comment: When you run locally, do the test processes need some manual interaction operations? In addition, have you tried to set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine to run the pipeline jobs?

Comment: Nope, they do not need any manual interactions. Im also not sure how to set up a self-hosted agent. Do you have a link on how to set that up?

Comment: @boolingBloke, See the following docs for configuring self-hosted agent on different OS:
- [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops)
- [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops)
- [Self-hosted macOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/osx-agent?view=azure-devops)